Upgrade from Ubuntu 22.04 LTS to 24.04 LTS failed about 75% complete
I selected to upgrade to 24.04 LTS in response to an upgrade message that I've had several times recently.  The process appeared to be going fine until it got to Phyton 3 where it flashed several error messages.  Then it displayed a message saying that it was going to restore settings but after 30 seconds it showed an "Installation Failed" message and advised a reboot.  After the reboot it showed "Something has gone wrong and the system can't recover please log out and try again" and this repeats every reboot.
I'm not a techie so please advise what to do?  Is there any way to revert back to the 22.04 LTS?

See at: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCdRecovery
